# Effective potential in static spherically symmetric spacetime and equivalence principle

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, equivalence-principle

In a static and spherically symmetric space-time, using the standard coordinates $\{t,r,\theta,\phi\}$
the geodesic equations imply that
$$
g_{rr}\biggl(\frac{dr}{d\tau}\biggr)^2+\frac{J^2}{r^2}-\frac{E^2}{g_{tt}}=-1
$$
where $J$ and $E$ are the conserved quantities and $\tau$ is the proper time along the curve. Dividing both sides by $g_{rr}$, one can make the equation have the usual kinetic+potential form
$$
\biggl(\frac{dr}{d\tau}\biggr)^2+V_{eff}(r)=E^2
$$
but the potential is in general $E$-dependent (the only case in which it's not is when $g_{tt}g_{rr}=-1$), so that different bodies experience different accelerations if they have different $E$. Does this dependence violates the equivalence principle? Or better, does it violate any of the equivalence principles?

Comment: I like your question!  I feel that since it is very simply derived from the metric, which clearly _is_ compatible with the EP, it cannot be in violation.  However I haven't found the flaw in your argument yet ;)  I have used the equations myself to plot orbits, but I always use M = mu = 1.

Comment: @GiulioNeri Have you found your answer? Recently, I have asked the same question, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/745457/281096, but did not get any answer as yet.

Comment: @JanGogolin Not yet

Comment: @GiulioNeri Maybe it helps you https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/747865/281096. The question is not exactly the same as yours but it concerns meaning of (effective) potential in General Relativity.